# Converting NSString to proper JSON format

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

Converting `NSString` to proper JSON format..

```
NSString *input_json = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"id\":\"%@\",\"seconds\":\"%d\",\"buttons\": \"%@\"}", reco_id, interactionTime, json_Buttons];
```

Here `json_Button` is in json format converted from nsdictionary..

My input_json result is:

```
{"id":"119","seconds":"10","buttons": "{
  "update" : "2",
  "scan" : "4"
}"}
```

It is not in a proper JSON format.  key buttons contain "{}" I want to remove these quotes.

Expected Result is:

```
{
    "id": "119",
    "seconds": "10",
    "buttons": {
        "update": "2",
        "scan": "4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going about this all wrong. First, create an `NSDictionary` that contains all of the data you want converted to JSON. Then use `NSJSONSerialization` to properly convert the dictionary to JSON.

Something like this will work:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"id" : reco_id, @"seconds" : @(interactionTime), @"buttons" : json_Buttons };
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
if (data) {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] intWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonString);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to convert dictionary to JSON: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Hi rmaddy am getting valid json.. but my server not accepting... your suggestion gave a result  like this.. JSON: {
  "id" : "119",
  "seconds" : 10,
  "buttons" : "{\n  \"update\" : \"2\",\n  \"scan\" : \"4\"\n}"
}  but my server expects that "buttons": {"update":"2","scan":"4"} like this... means that button key value should not be inside the "".. can u help me..

Comment: That's a whole separate issue. You should post a new question on that issue.  Be sure to include relevant details

Comment: Hi rmaddy am getting valid json.. but my server not accepting... your suggestion gave a result like this.. JSON: { "id" : "119", "seconds" : 10, "buttons" : "{\n \"update\" : \"2\",\n \"scan\" : \"4\"\n}" } but my server expects that "buttons": {"update":"2","scan":"4"} like this... means that button key value should not be inside the "".. can u help me..

Comment: Looks like an issue with your `json_Buttons` value.

Comment: Hi here is my json_Buttons value... {
  "update" : "2",
  "scan" : "4"
}  when i put all my values into nsdictionary it inserts the dictionary into like this,,,, {
    buttons = "{\n  \"update\" : \"2\",\n  \"scan\" : \"4\"\n}";
    id = 119;
    seconds = 10;
} I dont want my buttons values to be inside the quotes  "{}" like string...

Comment: Hi rmaddy.. can u help me to solve this.. i dont want my json_button value to be inside the "{}".. this double qoutes makes me tired ("")...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to try to build JSON strings manually. Use the NSJSONSerialization class. That makes it easy. Create your dictionary, then call `dataWithJSONObject:options:error:`.

If you use options: `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` it inserts line breaks and whitespace that makes the JSON more readable.

By using that function you get correctly formatted JSON every time, and it's flexible because if you send it a different dictionary you get different JSON.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply...Hi here is my json_Buttons value... { "update" : "2", "scan" : "4" } when i put all my values into nsdictionary it inserts the dictionary into like this,,,, { buttons = "{\n \"update\" : \"2\",\n \"scan\" : \"4\"\n}"; id = 119; seconds = 10; } I dont want my buttons values to be inside the quotes "{}" like string..

Comment: So edit your question to show the code that generates this JSON.